# What's the difference between "light up a lighter" and "light a lighter"

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is there any difference. It seems to me that "light up a lighter" means the same thing, but I've heard that they're not equivalent, and someone even told me it's not idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasal verb *light up* has three meanings, none of which fit here:

(From dictionary.com:)

1. to light a cigarette, pipe, etc
2. to illuminate or cause to illuminate
3. to make or become cheerful or animated

Only the first has anything to do with burning, and that one is intransitive: If you want to specify the item being lit, you don't use "up", so *light up* (in that sense) = *light a cigarette etc*.

Comment: In AmE we can "light up a cigarette" or just "light up".  *Keep the door closed in this wind until I can light up*. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22light%20up%20a%20cigarette%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: So light up a lighter means "illuminate or cause to illuminate a lighter"?

Comment: Both *light up a cigarette* and *light a cigarette* are fine. As are *light up the lighter* and *light the lighter*. The distinction you're making here isn't one that has any idiomatic bearing. (Unless this is another one of those regional differences.)

Comment: Ignite is a handy verb (as long as there is no gas around).

Comment: Hmm. _light up a cigarette_ gets 41 hits in the GloWbE corpus, against 94 for _light a cigarette_; so you would appear to be right (and it's not regional: UK gets more than US in both cases). It's different in the past: _lit up a cigarette_ gets only  16 hits, against 199 for _lit a cigarette_. But _light up a cigarette_ is not in my idiolect.